pull access denied for [region]-docker.pkg.dev/[project-id]/[repo]/[image], repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied
I'm trying to pull a Docker image from Google Artifact Registry using a service account, but I'm encountering a

Error response from daemon: pull access denied for
asia-southeast1-docker.pkg.dev/[project-id]/[repo]/[image], repository does
not exist or may require 'docker login': denied

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

Activated the service account:


gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=[path-to-key-file]


Configured Docker to use gcloud as the credential helper:


gcloud auth configure-docker asia-southeast1-docker.pkg.dev

I can log in successfully using gcloud and the service account.

Tried to pull the Docker image:


docker pull asia-southeast1-docker.pkg.dev/[project-id]/[repo]/[image]:[tag]

However, I'm getting the following error:

Error response from daemon: pull access denied for
asia-southeast1-docker.pkg.dev/[project-id]/[repo]/[image], repository does
not exist or may require 'docker login': denied

Additional Information
The service account has the following roles:
Artifact Registry Administrator
Artifact Registry Reader
Artifact Registry Writer     Owner
Project IAM Admin
Storage Admin
What I've Tried
Ensured that the service account key file is correct and activated.
I can push the image to the registry using the same account without any issues.
Questions
What could be causing the error?
Are there any additional steps I need to take to ensure that the service account has the correct permissions?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

You are following the instructions and so the expectation is that it will work. Are you confident that the image that you pushed was stored correctly? Consider adding gcloud artifacts docker tags list asia-southeast1-docker.pkg.dev/[project-id]/[repo]/[image] output to your question. If the Service Account was granted owner then you know that it isn't a permission issue.

We finally identified the issue: Hetzner IP addresses are blacklisted by Google. After changing the server, everything is working fine. This is a known issue with Hetzner. Consequently, we have decided not to use Hetzner for production environments.
